# Java's JPanel with GridLayout equivalent in WPF's XAML

Tags: c#, java, wpf, xaml, grid-layout

I would like declare in the XAML file a container that when I add any component to i it will behave like `JPanel` with `GridLayout` in Java. That means every component in that container will be the same size no matter I do.

Comment: The equivalent in WPF is UniformGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UniformGrid in WPF

```
<UniformGrid>
    <Button Content="Hello1"/>
    <Button Content="Hello2"/>
    <Button Content="Hello3"/>
    <Button Content="Hello4"/>
    <Button Content="Hello5"/>
    <Button Content="Hello6"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

[image: Uniform Grid Demo]

More info about UniformGrid here

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)